# homomorphic filter - python overflow

Tags: python, opencv, filtering

I'm trying to implement the homomorphic filtering as implemented by this research article - step 4 [(pdf)](http://stephanebazeille.com/publications/Bazeille_CMM06_1.pdf)

The original Matlab code, which I'm trying to translate into Python, is as follows (**WARNING:** only the **first case of the switch is relevant**):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Homomorphic filtering
% Stéphane BAZEILLE
% 15/10/07
%%%%%%%%%%

function result=homomorphic_filtering(I,type,RH,RL,cutoff)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% I = image (en niveau de gris et double entre 0 et 1)              %%
%% type= 'HighPassLiao' 'HighPassCufi' 'HighPassFilter'              %%
%%       'LowPassFilter' 'BandPassFilter' 'OnesFilter'               %%
%% !!!!!!!!! afficher avec imshow sans contrast_stretching !!!!!!!!! %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   

[rows,cols,dim]=size(I);

%figure;imshow(I);title('homo in');

% figure;hist(I,0.01:0.01:1.49);

disp(['Homomorphic filtering (',type,',',num2str(RH),',',num2str(RL),')']);

%Modélisation du filtre
if mod(cols,2) xrange = [-(cols-1)/2:(cols-1)/2]/(cols-1);
else           xrange = [-cols/2:(cols/2-1)]/cols;  
end
if mod(rows,2) yrange = [-(rows-1)/2:(rows-1)/2]/(rows-1);
else           yrange = [-rows/2:(rows/2-1)]/rows;  
end
[x,y] = meshgrid(xrange, yrange);
radius = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
switch type
        case 'HighPassLiao' 
            DX=cols/cutoff;
            G = ones(rows,cols);
            for m = 1:rows
                for n = 1:cols
                    G (m,n) = ((RH-RL)*(1-exp(-(((m-rows/2))*((m-rows/2))+((n-cols/2))*((n-cols/2)))/(2*DX*DX))))+RL;
                    %G (m,n) = ((RH-RL)*(1-exp(-(((m-rows/8))*((m-rows/8))+((n-cols/8))*((n-cols/8)))/(2*DX*DX))))+RL;
                end
            end
        case 'HighPassCufi'
            cutoff = 0.4; % 0 - 0.5
            offset = 0.5;
            boost  = 2;
            scale  = 50;
            G = boost./(1.0 + exp(-scale*(radius-cutoff))) + offset;
        case 'HighPassFilter' 
            cutoff = 0.3;  % 0 - 0.5
            n      = 3;    % n >= 1
            boost  = 0.2;  % 0<= boost=<1
            G = (1-boost)*(1 - (1 ./ (1.0 + (radius ./ cutoff).^(2*n))))+boost;
        case 'LowPassFilter'
            cutoff = 0.1;  % 0 - 0.5
            n      = 3;    % n >= 1
            boost  = 0.2;  % 0<= boost <1 
            G = (1-boost) ./ (1.0 + (radius ./ cutoff).^(2*n))+boost;
        case 'BandPassFilter'
            cutoff = 0.1;  % 0 - 0.5
            cutin  = 0.01; % 0 - 0.5
            n = 3;         % n >= 1
            G = (1 ./ (1.0 + (radius ./ cutoff).^(2*n)))-(1 ./ (1.0 + (radius ./ cutin).^(2*n)));
        case 'OnesFilter'
            G=ones(rows,cols);
end

%Filtrage homomorphique
if(dim==1)
    Idft=fft2(log(I+0.01));
    filtree=G.*fftshift(Idft);
    result=exp(real(ifft2(ifftshift(filtree))));
else
    Idft=fft2(log(I(:,:,1)+0.01));
    filtree=G.*fftshift(Idft);
    result(:,:,1)=exp(real(ifft2(ifftshift(filtree))));

    Idft=fft2(log(I(:,:,2)+0.01));
    filtree=G.*fftshift(Idft);
    result(:,:,2)=exp(real(ifft2(ifftshift(filtree))));

    Idft=fft2(log(I(:,:,3)+0.01));
    filtree=G.*fftshift(Idft);
    result(:,:,3)=exp(real(ifft2(ifftshift(filtree))));
end
end
```

It is called as follows:

```
%param: full image name
function prefilter_demo(name)

ori = imread(name);  
ori = double(ori)/255;
disp('Image Loaded');
figure;subplot(1,2,1);imshow(ori);axis off

tic;

disp('BEGIN FILTERING');
% EXTEND AND RESIZE IMAGE
[nl nc I ori]=picture_power_of_2(ori,5);
% CONVERT RGB TO YCBCR
ycbcr = rgb2ycbcr(I);
% HOMOMORPHIC FILTERING
ycbcr(:,:,1)=homomorphic_filtering(ycbcr(:,:,1),'HighPassLiao',2.5,0.5,32);
```

My problem is that I get an overflow error at the final exponential computation:

```
test_CV.py:64: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

I don't understand why, since I think my Python code is equivalent to the Matlab original one. I don't have a pre-processing stage to adapt the image size as a power of 2 pixels square, still, I execute my script on a 512x512 image.

Here is my Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('bleu_carree_512.jpg',-1)

rows,cols,dim=img.shape

rh, rl, cutoff = 2.5,0.5,32

imgYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
y,cr,cb = cv2.split(imgYCrCb)

y_log = np.log(y+0.01)

y_fft = cv2.dft(np.float32(y_log),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
y_fft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(y_fft)


DX = cols/cutoff
G = np.ones((rows,cols,2))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        G[i][j][0]=((rh-rl)*(1-np.exp(-((i-rows/2)**2+(j-cols/2)**2)/(2*DX**2))))+rl
        G[i][j][1]=((rh-rl)*(1-np.exp(-((i-rows/2)**2+(j-cols/2)**2)/(2*DX**2))))+rl


result_filter = np.multiply(y_fft_shift,G)

result_interm = np.real(cv2.idft(np.fft.ifftshift(result_filter)))

#################################
### OVERFLOW SOURCE BELOW #######
#################################

result = np.exp(result_interm) 

print(result.shape)

cv2.imshow('résultat',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

All the code associated with the article is available [here](https://sites.google.com/site/bazeilst/tutorials#TUTO9)

Thanks !

## EDIT & FIX:

Errors were indeed the lack of normalization **and** the usage of `cv2.dft()` which returns a 3 dimensional array. To be equivalent to the computation of `matlab fft2()`, I switched to `numpy.fft()` which returns a 2 dimensional array as Matlab does.

The resizing and symmetrization don't seem absolutely necessary (the corrected script worked without it).

Still, it appears `matlab rgb2ycbcr()` doesn't give the same Y component as `python cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)` (slight difference in the resulting arrays). That impacts all the following processing and final result.

Furthermore, Matlab doesn't need to de-normalize the resulting image in order to show the latter, whereas I needed to `result*255` to visualize it in my Python script. That has a tendency, along with the slight difference in the RGB->RCrCb transformation, to alter the "quality" of the filter translation into Python.

That being said, here is the functional python script, if it interests anyone:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# coding: utf-8

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('U352.jpg',-1)
img = np.float32(img)
img = img/255

rows,cols,dim=img.shape

rh, rl, cutoff = 2.5,0.5,32

imgYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
y,cr,cb = cv2.split(imgYCrCb)

y_log = np.log(y+0.01)

y_fft = np.fft.fft2(y_log)

y_fft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(y_fft)


DX = cols/cutoff
G = np.ones((rows,cols))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        G[i][j]=((rh-rl)*(1-np.exp(-((i-rows/2)**2+(j-cols/2)**2)/(2*DX**2))))+rl

result_filter = G * y_fft_shift

result_interm = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(result_filter)))

result = np.exp(result_interm)
```

Comment: Try using 128 bit precision as [suggested here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40726681/12570) This seems more like a SO question than a DSP question.

Comment: I don't know why, but the [numpy.longdouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062562/what-is-the-internal-precision-of-numpy-float128/17023995#17023995) "data type = 13 is not supported" on my system (Debian Stretch 64). Furthermore, according to your link, my exponential computation would overflow with **float128**. There must be an algorithmic mistake, I'm going to compare middle results with the original Matlab code. Thanks anyway ! (and sorry if off-topic)

Comment: Are any of the entries in `result_interm` about the same size as the number causing problems in that question (`1234.1`) ?  if so, it seems like you may need to scale things to fit.

Comment: there are of magnitude e+05, and I've tested my script with the test image of the original Matlab algorithm (with original preprocessing for resizing and extending symmetrically - cf. article), I still have those abnormal big values for **result_interm** (abnormal because way bigger than the max of the associated matrix in the original code). That surely means I've made an actual mistake in my translation of the algorithm/forgotten one entire step.

Comment: The original code appears to normalize the image with the line `ori = double(ori)/255;`. I can't see something similar in the python version.

Comment: You need to make sure the log function isn't trying to take the log of zero.  Check the inputs to the log function before doing log().   Clamp all other cepstrum intermediate values to a "reasonable" range.

Comment: Indeed for the normalization ! Looking into this right away. @hotpaw2 this is why I have log(y**+0.01**), and wouldn't I have an error/warning for that line if a log of zero happened ?

Comment: @PeterK. I managed to fix the script and edited my initial question accordingly. A few questions remain (see denormalization issue in Python, and RGB->YCbCr transformation difference between python and matlab), but the post issue is solved I guess. Thanks a lot for you help ! :-)

Comment: Excellent! Glad I was of some use. I still think it's off-topic here, but it's in a grey zone so I've reopened it. Please feel free to put your edit as an answer and give yourself the tick.

Comment: @PeterK. it would seem I can't give myself the tick (not enough reputation). And by "put your edit as an answer", did you actually mean add an answer where I just declare "see edit of initial post for solution" ? I'm new to this community and wish to understand how to correctly build relevant posts ^^

Comment: @Blupon Yes, I meant to add the edit as an answer.  You won't be able to give yourself the tick, I think, because the question isn't old enough yet. You'll need to wait a day or two longer to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## FIX:

Errors were indeed the lack of normalization **and** the usage of `cv2.dft()` which returns a 3 dimensional array. To be equivalent to the computation of `matlab fft2()`, I switched to `numpy.fft()` which returns a 2 dimensional array as Matlab does.

The resizing and symmetrization don't seem absolutely necessary (the corrected script worked without it).

Still, it appears `matlab rgb2ycbcr()` doesn't give the same Y component as `python cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)` (slight difference in the resulting arrays). That impacts all the following processing and final result.

Furthermore, Matlab doesn't need to de-normalize the resulting image in order to show the latter, whereas I needed to `result*255` to visualize it in my Python script. That has a tendency, along with the slight difference in the RGB->RCrCb transformation, to alter the "quality" of the filter translation into Python.

That being said, here is the functional python script, if it interests anyone:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# coding: utf-8

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('U352.jpg',-1)
img = np.float32(img)
img = img/255

rows,cols,dim=img.shape

rh, rl, cutoff = 2.5,0.5,32

imgYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
y,cr,cb = cv2.split(imgYCrCb)

y_log = np.log(y+0.01)

y_fft = np.fft.fft2(y_log)

y_fft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(y_fft)


DX = cols/cutoff
G = np.ones((rows,cols))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        G[i][j]=((rh-rl)*(1-np.exp(-((i-rows/2)**2+(j-cols/2)**2)/(2*DX**2))))+rl

result_filter = G * y_fft_shift

result_interm = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(result_filter)))

result = np.exp(result_interm)
```